# catdvi: "Does not start with preamble"

Tags: errors, debugging, bugs

Whatever input I give catdvi, it gives the same error: "Does not start with preamble".

For terseness, instead of posting my whole project here, I'll just paste an example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\begin{document}

This is the first paragraph of a typical document. It is
produced in a `12~point' size. A \emph{point} is a unit
of length used by printers. One point is approximately
$1/72$~inch. In a `12~point' font the height of the
parentheses is 12~points (i.e. about $1/6$~inch) and the
letter~`m' is about 12 points long. 

This is the second paragraph of the document. There are
also `10 point' and `11 point' styles available in LaTeX.
The required size is specified in the `documentstyle'
command. If no such size is specified then the 10~point
size is assumed.

\end{document}
```

Anyone have any idea about what's going on?

Edit: Oh, my apologies. I thought catdvi was something standard in LaTeX. I found it on the Wiki page here: https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Export_To_Other_Formats under "convert to plain text".

Comment: what is catdvi ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. @DavidCarlisle - I was about to pose the exact same question...

Comment: there is a command called `dviconcat` that gives a similar error if the input is not a dvi file.  `dviconcat: smpl.tex does not begin with a preamble`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: There is [catdvi](http://catdvi.sourceforge.net), according to the site the same was modified in 2002 for the last time, however there seems to be an update here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/catdvi/ from 2013

Comment: `catdvi` like `dvi2tty` indeed expects a `dvi` file not a `tex` file. So you first have to use `latex` (not `pdflatex`) to make a DVI from your TeX file and then run `catdvi` for the DVI file. If you want to extract the text from a TeX file try, e.g., `detex`.

Comment: Ah, thank you @Schweinebacke. Could you put that in an answer so that I can mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`catdvi` like most command line utilities with `dvi` in their name operates on DVI files not TeX files. So if you want to use `catdvi` (or `dvi2tty`) to extract the text from a TeX file, you first have to use `latex` (*not* `pdflatex`) to generate a DVI file. Then you can run `catdvi` (or `dvi2tty`) on the generated DVI file to convert it into plain text.

There are other utilities like `detex` to extract the text from a TeX file. But the result will differ from `catdvi` or `dvi2tty`.

BTW: There are also programs to convert PDFs into plain text, e.g., `pandoc` or `pdftotext`.